# Загрузка классов в Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

Я пишу скрипт, который  работает через *cron*, из чего выходит, что у него нет доступа к всем классам с *laravel*.

Как можно получить доступ к библиотекам не подключая их напрямую?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно написать [команду](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/commands) для Artisan, у которой ко всему будет доступ:

```
php artisan make:console FooCommand
```

Потом вызвать её по cron. Как-то так:

```
* * * * * php /path/to/the/artisan.php FooCommand
```

К тому же, в Laravel добавили [планировщик](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/artisan#scheduling-artisan-commands). В вашем случае он вроде ничем не поможет, но стоит иметь представление.